# is there a clear form field for flask?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

```
 submit = SubmitField("Submit")
```

the field above submits all information from a form into a DB. is there any way i can have something like a clearfield in flask whereby it clears any form input when clicked?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure Flask included anything like this, try making another button that redirects to the same page to get a fresh state.